# How can I calculate daily snapshots of my total sales on SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I have a table (let's call it DiodeSales) that tells me the total number of diode sales I made, grouped by date, diode color, and country. This is a sample of this schema:

```
Date                      Color   Country   Sales
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     1        
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        
June, 21 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     1        
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1
```

I want to be able to have have an additional column that tells me how many diodes we've sold up until that point. So, for example, using the above data, the {June 23, Red, 1, US} row would have a total sales value of 4, because we've sold 4 red diodes in the US at that point.

I initially thought a cumulative sum would do the trick. So I wrote this: (sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c949d/8))

```
SELECT
  t1.Date,
  t1.Color,
  t1.Country,
  t1.Sales,
  SUM(t2.Sales) AS CumulativeSales
FROM DiodeSales AS t1
INNER JOIN DiodeSales AS t2
ON t1.Date >= t2.Date
  AND t1.Color = t2.Color
  AND t1.Country = t2.Country
GROUP BY
  t1.Date,
  t1.Color,
  t1.Country
```

This gives me the cumulative sum, as expected, but it does not give me the total sales for a given color in a given country on a given day. In particular, because some specific days may have 0 sales in some country, they will not have a cumulative value associated to it. For example, consider the results of the previous table:

```
Date                      Color   Country   Sales    CumulativeSales
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        1
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     1        1
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        1
June, 21 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        2
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        2
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        3
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        3
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     1        2
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        4
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        4
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        5
```

If I were to look for the column corresponding to Japan on June 24, I'd find nothing (because there was no Japan sale that day, so there is no Japan row for that day). I don't think there's a way to do this in SQL, but is it possible to populate this resulting table with values on days in which some countries had no sales? The starting table will always have at least one column for each day for some country.

I am aware I could just write a simple

```
SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM DiodeSales
WHERE Date <= @someDate AND Color = @someColor AND Country = @someCountry
```

to get this information, but this is for a table that has to be formatted in that way for it to be used by another piece of already-made software.

EDIT: Someone mentioned this as a potential duplicate of  Calculate a [Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server), but that post only addresses efficiency while calculating a running sum. I already have various ways of calculating this sum, but I'm looking for a way to fix the issue of missing day/country combinations for days when there were no sales in that country. For the above example, the fixed query would return this:

```
Date                      Color   Country   Sales    CumulativeSales
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        1
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     1        1
June, 20 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        1
June, 21 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        0        1
June, 21 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     0        1
June, 21 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        2
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        2
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     0        1
June, 22 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        3
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        3
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     1        2
June, 23 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        4
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Green   US        1        4
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Red     Japan     0        2
June, 24 2016 00:00:00    Red     US        1        5
```

Comment: Added sql-server and sql-server-2016 to tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Comment: You tag your question with SQL-Server-2016, but SQLFiddle is created for MySQL. Which one is true?

Comment: So, have you tried my solution?

Comment: Yes. The result is the same as the solutions I posted in the fiddle. Also, pardon the confusion with the MySQL fiddle; the website seems to be having some issues with the SQL-Server options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [Date], Color, Country, Sales,
   SUM(Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY Color, Country ORDER BY [Date] rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY [Date], Color
```

It produces the output as expected.

**[EDIT]**

If you're looking for solution for missing dates, countries and colors, try this (replace `@tmp` with the name of your table):

```
SELECT A.[Date], A.Color, A.Country, COALESCE(B.Sales, 0) AS Sales
    ,   SUM(COALESCE(B.Sales, 0)) OVER(PARTITION BY A.Color, A.Country ORDER BY A.[Date] rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal
FROM (
    SELECT [Date], Color, Country
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM @tmp) AS q1 CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM @tmp) AS q2 CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM @tmp) AS q3 
    ) AS A
LEFT JOIN @tmp AS B ON A.[Date] = B.[Date] AND A.Color= B.Color AND A.Country = B.Country 
ORDER BY A.[Date], A.Color
```

Above query produces:

```
Date    Color       Country Sales   RunningTotal
2016-06-20  Green   Japan   0       0
2016-06-20  Green   US      1       1
2016-06-20  Red     Japan   1       1
2016-06-20  Red     US      1       1
2016-06-21  Green   US      0       1
2016-06-21  Green   Japan   0       0
2016-06-21  Red     US      1       2
2016-06-21  Red     Japan   0       1
2016-06-22  Green   Japan   0       0
2016-06-22  Green   US      1       2
2016-06-22  Red     Japan   0       1
2016-06-22  Red     US      1       3
2016-06-23  Green   US      1       3
2016-06-23  Green   Japan   0       0
2016-06-23  Red     US      1       4
2016-06-23  Red     Japan   1       2
2016-06-24  Green   Japan   0       0
2016-06-24  Green   US      1       4
2016-06-24  Red     Japan   0       2
2016-06-24  Red     US      1       5
```

Comment: This results in the same output I get with my query, so the issue of having days with missing countries is still there.

Comment: Sorry, add `[Date]` after `PARTITION BY ...`

Comment: @FedericoParedes, check my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use left join instead of inner join

```
  SELECT
 t.Date,
 t.Color,
 t.Country,
 t.CumulativeSales
 from DiodeSales t
 left join
 (SELECT
 t1.Date,
 t1.Color,
 t1.Country,
 t1.Sales,
 SUM(t2.Sales) AS CumulativeSales
 FROM DiodeSales AS t1
  GROUP BY
  t1.Date,
  t1.Color,
 t1.Country) t2
  on
 t.Date=t2.date
 and t.Color=t2.color
 and t.Country=t2.country
```

Comment: Why to force doors wide open, if there is simpleast way to achieve that?

Comment: Wouldn't this behave the same way as the INNER JOIN query, since we're joining the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Select distinct Date into SalesDate From DiodeSales

   SELECT S.Date,t.Color,t.Country,t.CumulativeSales
    from DiodeSales t left join
     (SELECt t1.Date,t1.Color,t1.Country,t1.Sales,
     SUM(t2.Sales) AS CumulativeSales FROM DiodeSales AS t1
      GROUP BY
       t1.Date,
       t1.Color,
     t1.Country) t2 on
       S.Date=t2.date
     and t.Color=t2.color
      and t.Country=t2.country
       join
      SalesDate S
      on t.date=S.date
```